# Placement of div-tags for layout

Tags: css, html

I have tried for hours now to get the placement of the divs correct. I now realize that I need some professional help.

[image]

The image should be pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I added your image, but *where is your code*? That's what we need to see to help you. Please click [edit] to add your HTML and CSS, and note the code formatting tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The link below should give you a good idea. I have set different background colours so that you can see where everything is. The only trouble you are going to have is that you cannot do "100% - 75px" so I have just set it as 500px.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/2UggG/)

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the constructive criticism. [Here is a fiddle with the code you posted.](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/Y6ew7/) It doesn't even resemble the photo slightly. 

It needs the outer container div so that the height on the left bar matches the height of the rest of the page.

Comment: You took my answer, applied the first solution to the problem I pointed out, and posted it as a jsFiddle of your own. Thanks for reminding me why I don't bother answering questions here any more.

Comment: I'm glad you think so much of yourself that you are able to make a few divs on a page and anyone who does something similar has copied your code. I didn't even read your anwser until after your first snide comment. Thanks for the downvote on an actual correct answer too. You're really getting into the spirit of helping people on this site :-)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu stuff</li>
    <li>More menu stuff</li>
    ...More items...
</ul>
<div id="header">
    ...Header content...
</div>
<div class="columns"><!-- This may be a candidate for a UL or an OL -->
    <div class="column"></div><div class="column"></div><div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    ...Content...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {float: left; width: 75px; height:100%;}
#header {height: 100px;}
.columns {height: 300px;}
.column {display:inline-block;width: 33.33%;}
```

It's important to keep the three `column` `div`s together to stop any whitespace appearing between them because of the `display:inline-block;`.

The only real problem here is the 100% height menu `div`. Because it's `float`ed (to push over the other content by 75px), the `height:100%` isn't working. There are 2 possible solutions to this:

1) Place everything bar the menu in a container `div` and give that a `margin-left:75px;`

2) Give the menu a fixed pixel height.